# Different Bootstrap Datepickers on same Button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I try to solve this problem for a few days now, but it seems that i can't, so I might need some help here :)

I want to display a Bootstrap Datepicker when the user clicks a button. But the type of the Datepicker depends on the selected Radio Button (Default is Year).

[image: Thats how it should work:]

I am not really a pro using Javascript and jQuery, but here is what I've tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="dateWrapper">
    <label class="btn btn-default ps-checkbtn @actY" id="datepicker_y">
        <input type="radio" id="q156" name="year" value="1" /> Year
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default ps-checkbtn @actM" id="datepicker_m">
        <input type="radio" id="q157" name="month" value="2" /> Month
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default ps-checkbtn @actD" id="datepicker_d">
        <input type="radio" id="q158" name="day" value="3" /> Day
    </label>

    <button id="chooseDate" class="ps_button">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Choose Date
    </button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#chooseDate').click(function () {
    if ($("#datepicker_y").is(":checked")) {
        $('#chooseDate').datepicker({
            minViewMode: "years"
        });
    else if ($("#datepicker_m").is(":checked")) {
        $('#chooseDate').datepicker({
            minViewMode: "months"
        });
    else if ($("#datepicker_y").is(":checked")) {
        $('#chooseDate').datepicker();
    }
});
```

The Result is, that the DateTimePicker appears, but only when I click on Day (twice), and it does not change the minviewmode.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `<input>` elements should be within a `<form>` element.

Comment: I dont want to submit the data yet, so its just an element to work with. There is no standard that you have to wrap input elements in a form, or at least I dont know a standard ;)

Comment: Yep, I just checked, you're absolutely right.

Comment: share datepicker() library file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Your solutions :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.dateselect').change(function () {
  initDatepicker($(this).val());
 });
 
 initDatepicker(1);// for first time initiate Day

});


function initDatepicker(mode){
    
 $('#datepicker-container').html(''+
     '<div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker"><input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" />'+'</div>');
  
    var $dtpicker=$('#datepicker-container > .input-daterange');
    $dtpicker.find(':input').val('');
 
    if (mode == 1) {//Day
        $dtpicker.datepicker({
            
            todayHighlight: true,
        });
    } else if (mode == 2) {//Month
        $dtpicker.datepicker({
            
            minViewMode: 1
        });
    } else if (mode == 3) {// Year
        $dtpicker.datepicker({
   minViewMode: 2
        });
    } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="dateWrapper">
    <label class="btn btn-default ps-checkbtn @actY" id="datepicker_y">
        <input type="radio" class="dateselect" id="q156" name="year" value="3" /> Year
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default ps-checkbtn @actM" id="datepicker_m">
        <input type="radio" class="dateselect" id="q157" name="month" value="2" /> Month
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default ps-checkbtn @actD" id="datepicker_d">
        <input type="radio" class="dateselect" id="q158" name="day" value="1" /> Day
    </label>

    
 <div id="datepicker-container"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx man :) Cool solution, guess I need some more JS Practice :D